# Find nth ROW in SQLiteDatabase in android

Tags: android, sqlite

How can i find `nth` ROW from SQLiteDatabase in android, i want something like this `SELECT * FROM Student WHERE rownum = 2;` Here `rownum` is not a part of **Table** in my DB looks like

**--------**
   Number
  **--------**
   123
   456
   789

So here i want to fetch row `456`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Student", null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                index=c.getColumnIndex("rownum");
                x=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(index));
                while(index!=-1) 
                {
                    if(x==456)//or n
                    {

                        //do something

                    }
                    else{

                        c.moveToNext();
                        index=c.getColumnIndex("rownum");
                        x=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(index));

                    }
                }
```

EDIT:

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Student", null);
c.moveToPosition(2);
```

Comment: if you want to select a number from a row then this is the most simplest way to do it

Comment: buddy but i want to get data which is on 2nd row coz database may be get updated so `456` order will be change but i always want 2nd record

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add add `LIMIT 1` and `OFFSET <n>` to the statement that you can execute like

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(SELECT_QUERY, null);
```

Comment: `Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName + "LIMIT 1;", null);` but this is not working

Comment: You are missing space before limit. try to use offset yet.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325515/sqlite-limit-offset-query-doubt)

Comment: i dont have tio specify buddy thats a problem

Comment: so when you add LIMIT 1 OFFSET 30, it will select  31st row. you must specify which row you want to select...

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table) yet for better understand.