# How to extract records in a sequential manner, from a table in Sqlite?

Tags: android, mysql

I have a table in Sqlite which contains three components for each record (eg A, ​​B, C), and the primary key (id) is random. I would like a SQL query that extracts each record sequentially, as if you were applying a loop to the database.

I know there is a clause like `LIMIT` but it only returns the first element (LIMIT 1) instead, two elements (LIMIT 2) ... but I want to extract a record, and process it and move on to another. Recalling that the id is random.

Comment: I you working with MySQL or SQLite?  I assume SQLite based on the Android tag.  You should certainly clarify.  Also seems like you may not fully understand how SQL works.  If you want ALL the records, then you shouldn't be using a LIMIT statement.

Comment: I'm not a Java user, but in general with SQL databases, you can run the query, and then loop through the rows one at a time. If you want to _extract a record, and process it and move on to another_ then it sounds like you're worried about memory consumption - so long as you loop through and don't store a lot of data per record, you should be okay.

Comment: You can use [OFFSET as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3325515/472495), in case you didn't already know.

Comment: Hello, I should just pull out a record that contains a photo that needs processing, then move on to another! Only having an id random and not sequential I do not know how to write the query as I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal to write the queries by hand as methods have been provided to generate safe queries.

```
database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {ROW_ID, ROW_COLUMN_ONE, ROW_COLUMN_TWO, ... }, null, null, null, null, new String[] {ROW_ID});
```

This will return all rows in your database ordered by the ROW_ID column.

This site might be of further use as it covers some common use cases for SQLite implementation.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

What kind of processing?

If you want to update or alter the data in some way, you can probably do it within SQL, but it sounds like you have something more complicated in mind that just "UPDATE table SET value_column = value WHERE key_column = key".

If that's the case you will need to extract the records and iterate through them in java.  Take a look at android.database.*.

Comment: Hello, I should just pull out a record that contains a photo that needs processing, then move on to another! Only having an id random and not sequential I do not know how to write the query as I do?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id;

Comment: so if I have a database with a table populated with 5 records this query returns me the first record, then the second ... up to 5? a bit like to do a "for loop" on table?

Comment: No, that SELECT statement will return all 5, in order from lowest id to highest.  Is there a problem with that?  Is the binary data of the photo embedded in the result set?  Are you trying to just go through the photos 1 at a time?