# Android SQLite Query - Getting latest 10 records

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database saved in my Android application and want to retrieve the last 10 messages inserted into the DB.

When I use:

```
Select * from tblmessage DESC limit 10;
```

it gives me the 10 messages but from the **TOP**. But I want the **LAST** 10 messages. Is it possible?

Suppose the whole table data is -

```
1,2,3,4,5....30
```

I wrote query `select * from tblmessage where timestamp desc limit 10`

It shows `30,29,28...21`

But I want the sequence as - `21,22,23...30`

Comment: you will need to change your query using ORDER BY clause as `SELECT * FROM tblmessage ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: I guess my table is not creating any _id column.

Comment: @Durpan If it is an SQLite database then it always has a `rowid` field (unless you specifically create the table with the `WITHOUT ROWID` clause). The `rowid` column is always indexed so will give fast results too.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Change the DESC to ASC and you will get the records that you want, but if you need them ordered, then you will need to reverse the order that they come in. You can either do that in your own code or simply extend your query like so:

```
select * from (
    select *
    from tblmessage
    order by sortfield ASC
    limit 10
) order by sortfield DESC;
```

You really should always specify an order by clause, not just ASC or DESC.

Comment: I want to reverse the order they come in. How Can I >

Comment: suppose the whole table data is -
1,2,3,4,5....30
I wrote query select * from tblmessage where timestamp desc limit 10
It shows 30,29,28...21
But I want the sequence as -
21,22,23...30

How Can I get the same

Comment: Awesome!  I wasn't aware that you could have nested selects like this.

Comment: For the proper ordering see @moodboom's answer

Comment: Should be SELECT ASC FROM DESC. Not DESC FROM ASC. Ascending gives you 1,2,3,4,5,6... Descending gives you 30,29,28,27... So first select descending as in the ones with highest value and down, form that select everything and flip the sort order.

Comment: A key point to note is that this query will only work quickly if you create an index on the field that you order by. This is obvious of you're used to SQL databases, but maybe not obvious to all readers here. If you just want database internal order, you can specify the `rowid` field in the `ORDER BY` clause (which is always indexed so you don't need to create an index yourself).

Answer (score 28):

on large databases, the `ORDER BY DESC` statement really might slow down the system, e.g. raspberry pi. A nice approach to avoid `ORDER BY` is the `OFFSET` command. And you even keep the stored order:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10 OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable)-10;
```

see: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

check out your performance with:

```
.timer ON
```

Comment: There is chance in this that offset could go negative which could raise exception

Comment: Of course you might call values off the upper and lower boundaries. However sqlite doesn't throw an exception, but returns all values possible.

Comment: I used this option, and it works as I want. It still safe with negative values.

Comment: **This does not work universally!** Without `ORDER BY` the results will be returned in arbitrary order. If you have a `WHERE` clause with an index, SQLite will return a different subset of data depending on its internal index lookup.

Comment: This solution MUCH faster and works even if the table has less rows than the maximum limit your are trying to get. It is great because if there are less rows than you just get all the rows in the table

Comment: This answer is much worse than the others: when using an `OFFSET`, SQLite has to go through ALL of the rows in between, which will be very slow for a large table. This is also true for `COUNT`, so this query is double slow! Using the nested `ASC` / `DESC` queries from the top answer will be much faster so long as (a) you specify an `ORDER BY` column, which you have to do anyway otherwise you rows might come back in a random order, and (b) the column in the `ORDER BY` is indexed, which it always will be if you order by `rowid`.

Answer (score 9):

Slightly improved answer:

```
select * from (select * from tblmessage order by sortfield DESC limit 10) order by sortfield ASC;
```

Michael Dillon had the right idea in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14018868/717274), but the example gives the first few rows, inverted order:

```
select * ... (select * ... ASC limit 10) ... DESC
```

He wanted the last, it should be:

```
select * ... (select * ... DESC limit 10) ... ASC
```

Comment: yes - select * ... (select * ... DESC limit 10) ... ASC

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c=database.rawQuery("sql Query", null);
if(c.moveToFirst) {
    int curSize=c.getCount()  // return no of rows
    if(curSize>10) {
       int lastTenValue=curSize -10;
       for(int i=0;i<lastTenValue;i++){
          c.moveToNext();
       }
    } else {
       c.moveToFirst();
    }
}
```

Then retrieve the last 10 data.

Answer (score 1):

If your table contains a column with primary key autoincrement (some "row_id" for example) then you just need single select with DESC order by this column

Raw request looks like

```
select * from table_name order by row_id DESC limit 10
```

Android implementation is

```
private Cursor queryLastEvents() {
    return getDatabase().query("table_name", null, null, null, null, null, "row_id DESC", "10");
}
```

Comment: This would give last 10 records but in REVERSE order.

Answer (score 1):

```
 "SELECT *  FROM( SELECT *  FROM " + tablename + whereClause + " ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10)  ORDER BY timestamp ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, the `DESC` is interpreted as a table alias.

As mentioned by ρяσѕρєя K, to be able to specify a sorting direction, you need to sort in the first place with an `ORDER BY` clause.

The column to be sorted should be a timestamp, if you have one, or an autoincrementing column like the table's primary key.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(select * from table_name order by yourfield ASC limit 10)
order by yourfield DESC;
```

You cannot have better solutions than this.

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.moveToLast();
while (cursor.moveToPrevious()){
       //do something
}
```

**with same query:** select * from tblmessage where timestamp desc limit 10

Comment: Some comment about why this is the right answer might help the person asking the question

Comment: I also face same type of problem in a Chatting App .but i am done by do this cursor.moveToLast();
while (cursor.moveToPrevious()){
       //do something
}