# Getting the 10 latest entries in SQL

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to get the the ten latest entries in my sqlite database. I need to fetch only one entry at a time instead of those ten entries at once.

Until now, i was doing this:

```
"SELECT " + sql + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME
                    + " WHERE _id = (SELECT max(_id)-2 FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ")";
```

For every entry i need, i was just doing `...max(_id)-x` but this does not work, if some entries are deleted at some time. The id's have some gaps (like 1, 2, 4, 8, ...).

So after some research i was trying something like this:

```
    "SELECT * FROM (SELECT " + sql + ", rank() over (order by max(_id) desc) rk 
FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " GROUP BY " + sql + ") t WHERE rk = 2"
```

this approach however crashes with the following message

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from (select price, rank() over (order by max(_id) desc) rk from refuels group by price) t where rk = 2
```

How can I get this done? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked into this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018394/android-sqlite-query-getting-latest-10-records?

Comment: @Ben alright, but how would i pick one of the ten entries?

Comment: What do you mean by how to pick one? http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html is a nice tutorial for sqlite

Comment: when i query like in that answer, don't i get all ten latest entries returned? I need to pick one of the ten entries.

Comment: Yes, your result will be 10 results (if there exist at least 10 entries in your table). Check out the tutorial I provided above - theres explained how to deal with the results of a query.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple and easy solution:

`"SELECT " + sql + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1 offset n"`

where the n is the number of the entry -1. Meaning, I want row number 6, n has to be 5.