# PHP Pagination : Prev and Next button work but table won't show up

Tags: php, paging

I'm following some example of PHP paging with ODBC on the internet and change them according to my own use.

I've managed to make to `NEXT` and `PREVIOUS` worked. The URL of the page change when the `NEXT` or `PREVIOUS` is clicked. For example when I clicked `NEXT` this is the URL `localhost/mypage.php?page=2`.

The issue here is the table of the data won't show up.

This is my code :

```
function inv_rows($r1)  
{
ob_start(); 
(int)$number = odbc_result_all($r1);
ob_clean(); 
return $number;
}

$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;  

if(empty($page)){$page = 1; 
}           
$query = "SELECT UserId, UserNm FROM User"; 
$num_result = odbc_exec($db, $query);
$numrows = inv_rows($num_result);   

$limit = 10;
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;

$sql = odbc_exec($conn,"SELECT UserId, UserNm FROM User LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset"); 


$result = odbc_exec($db, $sql);

echo "<table style='width: 600;'>";

while(odbc_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr>
<td style='width: 300; height: 15px;>";
echo odbc_result_all($result, "UserId");
echo "</td>
<td style='width: 300; height: 15px;'>";
echo odbc_result_all($result, "UserNm");
echo "</td>
</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
if($page !=1)
{
$pageprev = $page - 1;
echo "<a href='paging2.php?page=$pageprev' style='text-decoration: none'>&nbsp; PREVIOUS&nbsp;</a>";
}
else
{ 
echo "&nbsp; PREVIOUS &nbsp;"; 
}

if(($numrows - ($limit * $page)) > 0)
{
$pagenext = $page + 1;
echo "<a href='paging2.php?page=$pagenext' style='text-decoration: none'>NEXT</a>"; }
else
{ 
echo "&nbsp; NEXT &nbsp;"; 
}

odbc_free_result($result);            
exit;
?>
```

I'm sure I miss something. Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325515/sqlite-limit-offset-query) SO question.

Comment: Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325515/sqlite-limit-offset-query) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28860492/5016333) I change my code to `$sql = "SELECT UserId, UserNm FROM User LIMIT 10 OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User)-10";` . The table still won't show up. @JeroenHeier

Answer (score 0):

1. The code in your while function has raw HTML, and opens `<?php` script tags for PHP code.  Since you are already in PHP context, it should be the opposite way around - No need for opening and closing `<?php` tags, and HTML needs to be printed with PHP's `echo` command.
2. The `<table>` tag should be outside your while function.  You don't want to print a table for each row.

### Update:

3. Is `$conn` properly defined?  Is `$db` properly defined?
4. Does `$result` actually contain the rows you are interested in?

This should print a header row for your table.  If row data isn't printed, check your query result.

```
echo "<table style='width: 600;'>";
echo "<thead><tr><th>User ID</th><th>User Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

while(odbc_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr><td style='width: 300; height: 15px';>".odbc_result($result, 'UserId')."</td><td style='width: 300; height: 15px;'>".odbc_result($result, 'UserNm')."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: You mean `echo $result;` ? @user5855223

Comment: Well, you can do that.  It will print your result, but it might not look as beautiful as you would've wished...  You would need to print some html along with it, and print out the attributes from `$result` where they belong.

Comment: Sorry @user5855223 , I did echo them. See my updated code :)

Comment: I get it. I changed my code but the table still won't show up. I wonder if I wrongly implement the `$offset` and `$limit` . Any idea @ user5855223 ?

Comment: Do `echo $result;` as in your comment above.  What does that give you?

Comment: The table doesn't show up. The only thing printed are the `next` and `previous` . @user5855223

Comment: Any idea @user5855223 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
You must try and use the $offset variable in your query.

<?php
function inv_rows($r1)  
{
ob_start(); 
(int)$number = odbc_result_all($r1);
ob_clean(); 
return $number;
}

$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;  

if(empty($page)){$page = 1; 
}           
$query = "SELECT UserId, UserNm FROM User"; 
$num_result = odbc_exec($db, $query);
$numrows = inv_rows($num_result);   

$limit = 10;
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;

$sql = "SELECT UserId, UserNm FROM User LIMIT 10 OFFSET $offset"; 


$result = odbc_exec($db, $sql);

echo "<table style='width: 600;'>";

while(odbc_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr>
<td style='width: 300; height: 15px;>";
echo odbc_result_all($result, "UserId");
echo "</td>
<td style='width: 300; height: 15px;'>";
echo odbc_result_all($result, "UserNm");
echo "</td>
</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
if($page !=1)
{
$pageprev = $page - 1;
echo "<a href='paging2.php?page=$pageprev' style='text-decoration: none'>&nbsp; PREVIOUS&nbsp;</a>";
}
else
{ 
echo "&nbsp; PREVIOUS &nbsp;"; 
}

if(($numrows - ($limit * $page)) > 0)
{
$pagenext = $page + 1;
echo "<a href='paging2.php?page=$pagenext' style='text-decoration: none'>NEXT</a>"; }
else
{ 
echo "&nbsp; NEXT &nbsp;"; 
}

odbc_free_result($result);            
exit;
?>
```

Comment: I try `$sql = "SELECT UserId, UserNm FROM User ORDER BY UserId ASC LIMIT " . $limit . " OFFSET " . $offset;" " ;` and `$sql = "SELECT UserId, UserNm FROM User LIMIT 10 OFFSET $offset"` . Yet the table still doesn't show up. @SaurabhMore

Comment: Any idea @SaurabhMore ?