# Getting the last three records from SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database from which I would like to take the last 3 records. For example if I had the lines 1,2,3,4,5,6, ... 10,11,12,13,14, I would like 12,13,14 no matter the order (12,13,14 for me is equal to 14,13,12).
I tried to follow another question at this link [Android SQLite Query - Getting latest 10 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018394/android-sqlite-query-getting-latest-10-records)
 but what I get is just showing the first 3 rows of the database.

This is my query

```
String query2 ="select * from (select * from USERS order by ID ASC limit 3)";
```

Comment: use `desc` instead of `asc`

Comment: By the way, you don't need to double the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any case you can sort by [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) descending and get 3 rows:

```
select * from USERS order by rowid desc limit 3
```

If you want to sort by a specific column:

```
select * from USERS order by columnname desc limit 3
```