# SQL: SELECT All the fields from the SECOND BIGGEST ID

Tags: android, sql, performance, sqlite, select

My select looks like this and it returns the fields from the biggest id...

```
SELECT * FROM Pontos WHERE IdPonto = (SELECT MAX(IdPonto) FROM Pontos)
```

But now I want to select just the fields from the second biggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM Pontos WHERE IdPonto = (SELECT IdPonto FROM Pontos ORDER BY IdPonto DESC LIMIT 1,1)` should work.

Comment: Works... But just SELECT * FROM Pontos ORDER BY IdPonto DESC LIMIT 1,1 has the same effect... but i reached to it thanks your help

Answer (score 2):

This would be one way to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM Pontos ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

(Not quite certain about sqlite syntax, but read this SO thread for more info: [Sqlite LIMIT / OFFSET query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325515/sqlite-limit-offset-query-doubt))

edit: I do not think it is necessary in this case to run nested queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is written in standard SQL (it doesn't use LIMIT and OFFSET) and should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Pontos WHERE IdPontos = (
    SELECT MAX(t1.IdPontos) FROM Pontos t1
    WHERE t1.IdPontos not in (SELECT MAX(IdPontos) FROM Pontos)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I seems to do the job in standard SQL and in SQLite.

```
select * from Pontos where IdPonto < (select max(IdPonto) from Pontos) and IdPonto = (select max(IdPonto) from Pontos where IdPonto < (select max(IdPonto) from Pontos));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Pontos ORDER BY IdPonto DESC LIMIT 1,1
```