# Select SQLite field with index in C# without having ID field

Tags: c#, sqlite, select, indexing

My database is like this:

**Numbers**  | **Names**   |  **Surnames**

59266558 | John  | Smith 
56358656 | Ann   | Joyle 
59266558 | George| Colbyn 
59266558 | Gregor| Leon

As you can see, I have no ID field. So, the question is, how can I select  "Ann Joyle" ( with index 1), or "Gregor Leon" with index 3), and copy his/her number to `textBox` in C#?

Comment: Are You using EF or pure SQL?

Comment: I am using System.Data.SQLite Reference.

Comment: IMO my answer will help You

Comment: Thank you, I will try it

Comment: SQL tables are unordered. How is the index defined?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If You want to have `number` by `first` name and `surname` from table this is simple:

```
 SELECT Numbers WHERE Names= "Ann" and Surnames ="Joyle"
```

You get what You want.

If You want special index You can use in SQLLite syntax like this:

```
SELECT Numbers,Names,Surnames  WHERE LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

It is mean take 1 row and skip 1 row is equivalent to take index 1.

More info here: [Sqlite LIMIT / OFFSET query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325515/sqlite-limit-offset-query)

BUT

Your SQL table are unordere and the result of this query may be difrrent when You change something.

Good to do is use SQL ORDER BY keyword

```
SELECT Numbers,Names,Surnames  WHERE ORDER BY Surnames LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```