# about sqlite offset - What i do not understand?

Tags: select, sqlite, offset

If you check SELECT sqlite clause: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

You will see OFFSET demands EXPR. to get correct result from your database query.
And when I went checking what is EXPR. (Please see this: https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/expr.html) i see theoretically there should be a way to express a function after offset. For an example:

```
select * from my_table limit 50 offset count(id);
```

Count function would give you numeric value, however we know this is not possible. So my question is: Is there any way to add functions to offset or am I reading things in wrong way from links?

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to use functions in the LIMIT/OFFSET expressions:

```
SELECT 42 LIMIT length('x') OFFSET round(0.123);
```

The `count()` function does not work here because it is an aggregate function, and inside the OFFSET clause, there is no table or group over which it could be applied.

Answer (score -1):

It does not work in general. You have to select your count(id) in an extra query.

For more help look here: 
[Sqlite LIMIT / OFFSET query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325515/sqlite-limit-offset-query)

Comment: That link is not related to this question.